# Saving positions to database after drag and drop on RecyclerView element

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Drag and drop of elements is organized in RecyclerView. The data is retrieved from an SQLite database. Everything works! The problem is saving new positions to the database. Can only move the first element down 1 time. All of the following drags throw an error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: punkt._id (Sqlite code 1555), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)

I removed unique, still doesn't work.

AdapterSmetaFull.java

```
@Override
public void onRowMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
        for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
            Collections.swap(mPeopleList, i, i + 1);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
            Collections.swap(mPeopleList, i, i - 1);
        }
    }
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);

    long movedItem = mPeopleList.get(fromPosition).getId();
    long draggedItem = mPeopleList.get(toPosition).getId();

    // updating
    final DatabaseAccessSmeta databaseAccessSmeta = DatabaseAccessSmeta.getInstance(mContext);
    databaseAccessSmeta.open();
    DatabaseAccessSmeta db = new DatabaseAccessSmeta(mContext);

    db.open();
    db.updateOrder(draggedItem, toPosition);
    db.updateOrder(movedItem, fromPosition);
    db.close();
}
```

PersonSmetaPunkt.java

```
public class PersonSmetaPunkt {

private long id;
private long smeta_id;
private String vid_rabot;
private String kolichestvo;
private String zena;
private String valuta;
private String slogenie;

public PersonSmetaPunkt() {
}

public PersonSmetaPunkt(long smeta_id, String vid_rabot, String kolichestvo, String zena, String valuta, String slogenie) {
    this.smeta_id = smeta_id;
    this.vid_rabot = vid_rabot;
    this.kolichestvo = kolichestvo;
    this.zena = zena;
    this.valuta = valuta;
    this.slogenie = slogenie;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public long getSmeta_id() {
    return smeta_id;
}

public void setSmeta_id(long smeta_id) {
    this.smeta_id = smeta_id;
}


public String getVid_rabot() {
    return vid_rabot;
}

public void setVid_rabot(String vid_rabot) {
    this.vid_rabot = vid_rabot;
}
```

DatabaseAccessSmeta.java

```
 public void updateOrder(long rowID, int newPos) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("_id", newPos);
    database.update("punkt", cv, "_id" + "=" + rowID, null);
}
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE "punkt" (
"_id"   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
"smeta_id"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
"vid_rabot" TEXT NOT NULL,
"kolichestvo"   NUMERIC NOT NULL,
"zena"  NUMERIC NOT NULL,
"valuta"    TEXT NOT NULL,
"slogenie"  NUMERIC NOT NULL);
```

Table before dragging:

[image]

Table after dragging:

[image]

What could be the problem? Perhaps it is in these lines:

```
long movedItem = mPeopleList.get(fromPosition).getId();
long draggedItem = mPeopleList.get(toPosition).getId();
```

Why is 0 added to the table?